# Endian-ness in a char array containing binary characters

Tags: c++, endianness

I'm building some code to read a RIFF wav file and I've bumped into something odd.

The first 4 bytes of the file header are the word RIFF in *big-endian* ascii coding:

```
   0x5249 0x4646
```

I read this first element using:

```
char *fileID = new char[4];
filestream.read(fileID,4);
```

When I write this to screen the results are as expected:

```
std::cout << fileID << std::endl;
>>  RIFF
```

Now, the next 4 bytes give the size of the file, but crucially they're *little-endian*.

So, I write a little function to flip the bytes, based on a union:

```
int flip4bytes(char* input){

   union flip {int flip_int; char flip_char[4];};

   flip.flip_char[0] = input[3];
   flip.flip_char[1] = input[2];
   flip.flip_char[2] = input[1];
   flip.flip_char[3] = input[0];

   return flip.flip_int;

 }
```

This looks good to me, except when I call it, the value returned is totally wrong. Interestingly, the following code (where the bytes are *not* reversed!) works correctly:

```
int flip4bytes(char* input){

   union flip {int flip_int; char flip_char[4];};

   flip.flip_char[0] = input[0];
   flip.flip_char[1] = input[1];
   flip.flip_char[2] = input[2];
   flip.flip_char[3] = input[3];

   return flip.flip_int;

 }
```

This has thoroughly confused me. Is the union somehow reversing the bytes for me?! If not, how are the bytes being converted to int correctly without being reversed?

I think there's some facet of endian-ness here that I'm ignorant to..

Comment: A char-array does not *have* a notion of endianness. It's just an array of bytes, one after the other. Endianness only applies to types which are wider than one byte, like an `int`. Also, do you mean `char flip_char[4]` in your union?

Comment: I did yes, edited to reflect this. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are simply on a little-endian machine, and the "RIFF" string is just a string and thus neither little- nor big-endian, but just a sequence of chars. You don't need to reverse the bytes on a little-endian machine, but you need to when operating on a big-endian.

Answer (score 2):

You need to figure of the *endianess* of your machine. `#include <sys/param.h>` will help you do that.

You could also use the fact that network byte order is big ended (if my memory serves me correctly - you need to check). In which case convert to big ended and use the `ntohs` function. That should work on any machine that you compile the code on.